# Nodejs Express - Is it expected for the leading whitespaces in HTTP headers to be stripped?

Tags: node.js, express, http, header, postman

I am using Postman to make a POST request to my nodejs API. Notice how my password value has many leading spaces:

[image]

Postman code also shows the spaces:

[image]

But in my nodejs API using express, when I console log the headers `req.header("password")`, it only prints the `thisHasALeadingSpace` and doesn't have the spaces before.

Is this a bug? I tested with trailing spaces and they are printed fine. But leading spaces are not. Is this a bug in express?

**EDIT:** I just found this:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers

It says "Leading white space before the value is ignored." So I guess I shouldn't be using HTTP header for sending username/password in case user uses a space in the beginning of their password?

Comment: Relevant portion of http spec: https://greenbytes.de/tech/webdav/rfc7230.html#header.fields.  `header-field   = field-name ":" OWS field-value OWS` where `OWS` is optional whitespace (one or many) as described here: https://greenbytes.de/tech/webdav/rfc7230.html#whitespace.  So, the actual header value should have leading and trailing whitespace trimmed.

Comment: @jfriend00 I am not understanding it. Does it mean a leading whitespace as part of the field-value should be respected or not?

Comment: @jfriend00 but express respects trailing white spaces. It only doesn't respect leading ones. If I put trailing whitepaces, express prints it correctly.

Comment: Well, the official "field-value" per the http specification is after removing both leading and trailing whitespace.  The way Express is returning the value to you, you can go with whichever one you want.  You can either use it as or you can call `.trim()` on it to remove extra whitespace.  I don't know why Express is doing it the way it is.

Comment: @jfriend00 ok thanks. One more related question. I have read some people recommend using the header for username passwords while others recommend using the body. The way express is working with leading white spaces, it seems that using the header isn’t the right way. What’s your opinion on this?

Comment: I don't have knowledge on best way to send passwords.  Usually, they are in POST bodies, not headers, but auth tokens are often in headers.  I would worry about transmitting passwords over http in the clear.  You can put quotes around the password and then trip them later if you want to be sure to capture leading and trailing whitespace.

Comment: @jfriend00 ok thanks for the reply! Appreciate it! If you post this as answer, I will accept it.

Comment: Your question was marked a duplicate of another similar question that contains the specification reference I pointed to so there are no answers here.